# android openGL ES live wallpaper - when to load and create textures?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to make an openGL live wallpaper which uses a number of textures. Some of which are quite large, full screen images.

I'm not sure how I should load the bitmaps and binding the textures. For example, I could load them in the `onSurfaceCreated()` method:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config){    
     ...
     Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.background, null);
     gl.glGenTextures(1, backgroundTextureArray, 0);
     gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, backgroundTextureArray[0]);
     gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
     gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
     GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0, background,0);
}
```

However, I believe this would mean that every time the wallpaper become visible, it would have to load the images into memory again. This doesn't seem like a good idea in general considering the wallpaper will go in and out of view often.

Is there another way to setup the textures? I'm not sure what happens when a program is running and needs extra memory. If the LWP can be killed, then maybe I can store the bitmaps permanently whilst the wallpaper service is alive?